# redirecting TCP stream to another client

Tags: linux, tcp, stream, iptables

I have a TCP server that only allows a few clients to connect to it. However the data transfer is purely unidirectional -- the server sends all the data to the client and the clients little to no data back to the server. Is there a way to use iptables or firewalls to redirect the TCP stream leaving the server to the client to another TCP client?

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to cook up a sketchy packet sniffing scheme to do this, but the second client cannot be a standard tcp client.

There is no such thing as a unidirectional TCP connection.  The PAYLOAD -- the application data transfer -- may be unidirectional, but TCP itself is a bidirectional, acknowledged, protocol, with state maintained at both ends and updated by control messages or control information piggybacked on data messages.  The state is also updated by timeouts -- failures to receive control packets within a specified time.

TCP will turn 30 in September.  Here is the RFC, written by Jon Postel of blessed memory.  See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt

The state diagram for the protocol entity at each end is shown in Figure 6.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Maybe there's a more clever way of accomplishing what I want -- would I be able to say run a tcpdump on the data I want and then pipe that as an input on to a program that reads it in as a buffer?

Comment: Sure.  That's my "sketchy packet sniffing scheme."